# Won't print anything on terminal

Tags: go

I would like to know why when I execute the command `go run example.go` the won't print anything on terminal.

The code below works.

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    fmt.Println("Hello")
}
```

Will print `Hello`.

But when I would like to use the function `fmt.Printf` when I run the command to execute, appear very quickly the response but is deleted on terminal.

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    var i int = 2
    fmt.Printf("%v %T", i, i) // fmt.Print does not work to
}
```

Comment: Never use `go run <file>.go`

Comment: Does it not print, or it prints then disappears? Those two descriptions are entirely different, and contradictory.

Comment: Why never use `go run` @Flimzy

Comment: I didn't say don't use `go run`. I said don't use `go run <file>.go`. And the reason is that you should be compiling a complete package, not individual files.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You use `fmt.Printf` with a format that does not end with a newline, so your system dutifully prints out the output without a terminating newline.

Presumably your *shell* then *overwrites* the output by sending the cursor to the beginning of the line and printing something.  To prevent this from happening, either have your program end its output with a newline, or update your shell's prompt to avoid printing over existing output.

(Side note: it's just `Go`, not `Go Lang`.  This goes give some issues with searching, common among short-named languages like C and C++.)

Answer (score 1):

When `Printf` is used, you need to put a `\n` at the end.

Answer (score 0):

Your program will produce `undefined: I`.
By replacing `I` with `i` it should work https://play.golang.org/p/GxFh-SYePR3 and return `2 int`.

Comment: Sorry @Vor, I typed wrong now I edited the post.

Comment: At the `The Go Playgroud` works but on my VSCode does not.

Comment: I found the answer, when `Printf` is used, you need to put a `\n` at the end